# Where to edit Prestashop Checkout Summary page Delivery address fields

Tags: prestashop

I am using PrestaShop™ 1.4.9.0 version.

Now I'm trying remove "Phone" field in checkout page on first step(Summery page). I am trying but no luck.

How to find it?

Comment: There is no phone number field on the shopping cart summary page only on the "Create your account" page. Do you want to remove those?

Comment: Hi thanks your comment. I want remove here http://oi61.tinypic.com/ionngi.jpg

Comment: Now I see that guest checkout is turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines from `authentication.tpl`:

`{elseif $field_name eq "phone"}
 <p class="text">
   <label for="phone">{l s='Phone'}</label>
   <input type="text" class="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="{if isset($smarty.post.phone)}{$smarty.post.phone}{/if}"> <sup style="color:red;">*</sup>
 </p>`

Copy the `preProcess` method from `controllers/AuthController.php`

Create `override/controllers/AuthController.php`:

```
<?php
class AuthController extends AuthControllerCore
{
}
```

Paste `preProcess`

Delete line `parent::preProcess();`

Remove these lines:

```
if (!Tools::getValue('phone') AND !Tools::getValue('phone_mobile'))
  $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must register at least one phone number');
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. Where to find authentication.tpl file. Because i'm find file in theme folder. And remove that code but no luck. Please  tell which file edit ?

Comment: Hi thanks your commend. i'm searching my custom theme folder and find some files. I remove and check it. But no luck. Any idea any other files?

Comment: @vino Are `Force compile` and `Cache` set to `No` in `Back Office` -> `Preferences` -> `Performance`?

Comment: lot of thanks. Preferences is set to No now changed to Yes. Now phone number field is removed. Thank you so much yenshirak.